# Cannot find symbol using System.out.println(""); (NetBeans, IntelliJ or Eclipse)

Tags: java, class

*Bad english alert*
Whenever I try to use System.out.println on another class besides main, every single IDE installed in my PC returns the error on the title.

I'm writing a really simple code.

On IntelliJ, I had already tried to use "Invalidated caches" but didn't work as well.

Works here:

```
package javaapplication3;

public class JavaApplication3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println("Hi");    /* <-- This works on main, but doesn't
                                     work in any other class opened in 
                                     another tab*/
}
```

But not in this other tab:

```
 package javaapplication3;

 public class NewClass {
  System.out.println("Hi");
 }
```

## UPDATE

Here some images to specify the problem: [Work here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RS0B3.png), [but not here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOLwe.png).

Comment: Can you update your question with where _but doesn't
                                     work in any other class opened in 
                                     another tab_

Comment: Can you please show example code of where you're seeing the error while using `System.out.println` along with the error message?

Comment: "I'm writing a really simple code." - Then it shouldn't be a problem to post a [mcve] :) - Showing us what works doesn't help, we need to see what you've tried that didn't work (and ideally as much information on "didn't work" as well, e.g. error messages, lines markes etc.)

Comment: Is your class called `System`?

Comment: The main class name is JavaApplication3

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information. I had put some images above.

Comment: Please somebody help me! I just want to study the language but can't even use a IDE without errors.

Comment: There already is a valid answer from Alen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**All code has to be in methods.**

The command `System.out.println("")` will **work only in a method**.

Placing it under a class but not a method will result in the compiler throwing an error.

Eg:

```
public class test {    // class
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // inside main method
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");  // correct
    }
}
```

will work perfectly fine.

But, if you place the command under just a class, it's going to result in an error.[Needs to be in a certain method]

Eg:

```
public class test{
    // inside a class, but no method
    System.out.println("Hello, World!"); //incorrect
}
```

Also, you need to make sure your class and function are not reserved keywords.

And from what you've specified above, `main` in not a class but it's the main method of the class.

Comment: I've posted two images to specify the problem. Can you check them please?

Comment: The reason why it doesn't work in the second one is because the System.out.println(""); statement isn't inside a method but only inside a class. Put that into a class and it shall work. Refer the example code I've posted.